# Convert an Array of integers to a String

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, android-activity

First, I'm completely new to Java programming (just started 3 weeks ago), and I tried my best for two days to solve it. but with no success.

I have this class that reads mp3 files from SD-Card:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path
    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/audio");
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }
}
```

***Problem***: my application contains 4 classes, and all are using `ArrayList< HashMap< String, String >>`. So, I need to keep using `ArrayList< HashMap< String, String >>`.

***Must***: `getPlayList()` return type should be always `ArrayList< HashMap< String, String >>`. Since I'm using that method on the other classes.

***Goal*** : I want to create an array of audio files (stored in raw folder) inside `SongsManager` class :

```
int[] lessonClips = { R.raw.button_1, R.raw.button_2, R.raw.button_3, R.raw.button_4, R.raw.button_5, R.raw.button_6 };
```

and let the MusicPlayer read this array instead of reading from a path.
It's kind of customize this class to play that **LessonClips** only.

***Question***: How can I modify getPlayList to manipulate `LessonClips` and still return a `songList` of type `ArrayList< HashMap< String, String >>`?

Answer (score 0):

I have just skimmed through what you have said you want and I feel that declaring lessonclips as an instance variable might solve your purpose. That way you can update lessonclips in any function you want and return whatever type you want from the function.
Something like below:-

```
public class SongManager{
       private int[] lessonclips;

       public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
           //do whatever you want with lessonclips
           //and return your arraylist which you wanted to return

       }

      public int[] getLessonClips{
         return lessonclips;
        }
```

Comment: I need that songList returned by getPlayList to be passed to other classes. This songList somehow should have LessonClips inside of it. What is the purpose of getLessonClips then?